# Proper Indexing MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

As far as indexing goes, is it proper to index all fields that will be searched (within a WHERE) clause to speed up SELECTS?  For example my database contains a profiles table which stores user information such as name, intrestCode,zip, description, and email.  The profile record is identified by a PRIMARY id column which uniquely corresponds with the userid.  I made zip and intrestCode an index since profiles will be searched by zip and possibly intrestCode (`` SELECT `blah`,`blah`... FROM profile WHERE zip=? ``, `` SELECT `blah`,`blah`... FROM profile WHERE zip=? && intrestCode=? ``).  Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds basically correct. You should be aware that you can't use two different indices on the same table in the same query, so if you ran

```
CREATE INDEX `zip` ON `profile` (`zip`);
CREATE INDEX `intrestCode` ON `profile` (`intrestCode`);
```

then the query

```
SELECT `blah`,`blah`... FROM profile WHERE zip=? && intrestCode=?
```

can only look up one table from the index. The secret here is that you can create a single index on two tables, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX `zip+intrestCode` ON `profile` (`zip`, `intrestCode`);
```

MySQL can use this for queries that use either `zip` alone in the WHERE clause, or use both `zip` and `intrestCode`, but not for queries that use only `intrestCode` in the WHERE clause.

(This is because each index covers the whole table. If MySQL were to try and look up `zip` and `intrestCode` from different tables, then it would be retrieving lots of irrelevant rows  from the second index. Therefore, it only looks at one index. If you want it to use the index on both columns, you need to have one index that includes both columns.)

Comment: The issue is I don't know how users want to search.  Some may want to search by zip code only, some may want to search by interest only, and some might want to search by both.  This seems like a common occurrence.  There is no solution (short of many tables)?  Would building a multicolum index and wildcarding the unused fields work? For Zip only: SELECT * FROM profiles where zip = ? && intrestCode LIKE '%'.  For Intrest code only: SELECT * from profiles WHERE zip LIKE '%' && intrestCode = ?.  For both: SELECT * from profiles WHERE zip = ? && intrestCode=?.

Comment: No. There has to be a strict relationship between the fields. If you have two fields, you can easily create two indices, one on `zip` and `intrestCode` and one on just `intrestCode`. If you have more fields, it gets harder to account for all of the combinations. At that point it's probably best to create one index for each field and let the optimizer pick the best one (event though you can't get the same kind of efficiency gain). It may not be worth it to create multicolumn indices at all depending on the size of the DB. Some judgment calls are necessary here.

Comment: One more question, will adding several indices to cover many combinations actually slow down things (come UPDATE, INSERT, or even SELECT time?), or is it just costly in terms of disk space.  Disk space is a near infinite resource due to the low cost.

Comment: It slows things down at UPDATE and INSERT time, but probably only a little (unless your table is incredibly huge, in which case you get a big advantage from having lots of indices at SELECT time). It's mostly a matter of disk space. If you have lots of columns, however, you do need to be wary of creating too many indices, because the number of indices you would create grows exponentially with the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing relation datbases is a bit of an art. The best approach is to look at all the different queries you will be making and putting indices on the columns involved. Use `EXPLAIN` to see what indices a query is going to use.

However, remember that MySQL can only use one index from a table at a time. This is why you can put an index on multiple columns at once. And MySQL can use a multi-column index if it only needs the columns in the start of the index. In your example, I would put a multi-column index `zip` and `intrestCode` together because that will help both queries. That way you don't need a separate index on just `zip`.

Comment: So how would one speed up SELECT `email`,`name` FROM `profiles` WHERE `zip` = ? && `intrestCode` = ? .  As you can see it uses 2 columns.  I wouldn't use 2 separate indices?

Comment: You do a multi-column index: `ALTER TABLE profile ADD INDEX (zip, intrestCode)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe basically yes. You should monitor your database to encounter further problems and optimize your queries and tables based on the results too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to add indexes to columns that you will join on or have in your where clause.  Remember that an index on two columns is different than one index on each of the two columns.  Also if you have an index on multiple columns the order matters.

Say you have two columns A and B and have an two column index in the order A then B. There are three cases:

1. Where clause against column A: index is used
2. Where clause against column B: index is NOT used
3. Where clause against columns A and B: index is used

Like staticsan says, indexing is an art and there are no rules that apply 100% of the time.  Use the explain plan to see how your query is performing and make tweaks accordingly.